# Problems saving an object with Restangular

Tags: angularjs, restangular

How do I save new objects with Restangular?
When I do a save() on my customer object I get this error. Any idea why?

```
saving "customer name" customers.js?body=1:14
TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

**HTML**

```
<form ng-submit="save(customer)">
  <input type="text" ng-model="customer.name">
```

**Controller** *(coffeescript)*

```
$scope.save = (customer) ->
  console.log("saving '#{customer.name}'")  # this works
  customer.save()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. This works. :-)

```
1 angular
2   .module('app')
3   .controller "CustomersCtrl", ($scope, Restangular) ->
4
5     # Initalize the Customer object
6     Customer = Restangular.all('customers');
7
8     $scope.getCustomers = () ->
9       Customer.getList().then (customers) ->
10         $scope.customers = customers
11
12     $scope.save = (customer) ->
13       Customer.post(customer)
```